# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el atributo selected a un select de forma dinámica con PHP?

Tags: php, bootstrap

Necesito poner el atributo selected a un select de forma dinámica lo estoy intentando asi pero no funciona.

```
<select class="form-control" name="rol" id="rol" onkeypress="return tabular(event,this)" required>
            <option value="">Tipo de usuario</option>
            <?php while($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {?>                  
            <option value="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>" 
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['campos'])){
            if($fila['id']==$_SESSION['campos']['rol'])
            {echo "selected";}
            }?>>
            <?php echo $fila['nom_tipo'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

Me ayudaria mucho y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es imprimir todo el código del *option* entero en lugar de solo agregarle la palabra "selected".

```
<select class="form-control" name="rol" id="rol" onkeypress="return tabular(event,this)" required>
    <option value="">Tipo de usuario</option>
    <?php while($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)):?>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['campos'])):?>
            <?php if($fila['id']==$_SESSION['campos']['rol']): ?>
                <!-- Si se cumple la condición, se agrega "selected" -->
                <option value="<?=$fila['id'];?>" selected> <?=$fila['nom_tipo'];?></option>
            <?php else:?>
                <!-- No se cumple la condición -->
                <option value="<?=$fila['id'];?>"> <?=$fila['nom_tipo'];?></option>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona a la perfección!!!!!!

Comment: @victor Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta. :D